# Unable to type text in email body for Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, gmail

I want to create the send gmail function, but the code can only send empty body gmail. I guess the frame switch is not correct. Could someone tell me which frame is for gmail composing? I tried to search a lot of resolution online, but did not get the answer. Because google has changed the gmail html details a lot, I could not find the way. I am new for selenium, so if you can figure out how to find the frame in the html, I will appreciate your help.

Thanks a lot!

```
package com.email.test;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class send_email {
    private static WebDriver driver; 
    private static String baseUrl;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String username = "robertredrain@gmail.com";
        String password = "robertIlinda1987RED";
        ComposeMail(username, password); 
    }

    public static void ComposeMail(String username, String password) throws InterruptedException{
        Date dNow = new Date();
        SimpleDateFormat subjectdate = new SimpleDateFormat("E yyyy.MM.dd 'at' hh:mm:ss a zzz");
        String emailsubject = "Current time" + subjectdate.format(dNow).toString();
        String tomailid = "robertredrain@yahoo.com";
        String mailbody = password + "\n" + "Great! you sent email:-)" + "\n" + "Regards," + "\n" + "Robert";
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        baseUrl = "https://mail.google.com";
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        /* Navigate to Gmail */
        driver.get(baseUrl+"/intl/en/mail/help/about.html");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        /* Enter username and password */
        driver.findElement(By.id("gmail-sign-in")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("Email")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.id("Email")).sendKeys(username);
        driver.findElement(By.id("next")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("Passwd")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.id("Passwd")).sendKeys(password);
        driver.findElement(By.id("signIn")).click();
        //System.out.println(driver.getTitle()); Inbox (8,142) - robertredrain@gmail.com - Gmail

        /*Verify login*/ 
        String title = "Gmail";
        if(driver.getTitle().contains(title)){
            System.out.println("Logged in sucessfully !!!" + driver.getTitle());
        }else{
            System.out.println("Unable to loggin :-( " + driver.getTitle());
        }

        /* Compose email */
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[7]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.className("vO")).sendKeys(tomailid);
        driver.findElement(By.className("aoT")).sendKeys(emailsubject);
                    driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[@tabindex='-1']")));

        WebElement printbody = driver.switchTo().activeElement();
        printbody.sendKeys(mailbody);
        driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[text()='Send']")).click();
    }

}
```

Comment: We don't really need to know your gmail password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to switch to frame here. just do the same as the subject and recipients

```
 driver.findElement(By.className("Am")).sendKeys("some text");
```

> Edit

To insert text with signature you send the text to the div child

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".Am > div")).sendKeys("some text");
```

Comment: Your code works if I disable the Signature option. Is there any way I can add text with signature?

Comment: Another question is that where did you find the class name "Am"? When I  "Inspect Element" at the composing email body, class name shows "Am Al editable LW-avf", but this does not work.

Comment: @robertredrain I added solution for the signature

Comment: @robertredrain And for your question, "Am", "Al", "editable" and "LW-avf" are four different classes, you can locate your element by each one, all together `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".Am.Al.editable.LW-avf"))` or using two or three of them.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Could you pls specify how to locate the "Am" element in the webpage?

Comment: @robertredrain right click on the mouse -> "Inspect". The developer tools will open withe the element marked

Comment: If my solution solved your problem feel free to accept it by clicking on the sign next to it :)

Comment: but when I right click on the mouse on the New Message body, it gives me   class = "Am Al editable LW-avf". How could I know which element is the one I want?

Comment: @robertredrain Those are four classes of the same element, you can choose either one or some of them together (look at my comment above from 40 minutes ago).

Comment: Got it. Thanks so much for the quick reply. really appreciate it.

Comment: One more question is not sure why use id it does not work: driver.findElement(By.id(":13d")).sendKeys(mailbody);

Comment: @robertredrain In my computer the id is ":14s" so I guess its dynamic and changes every time.

Comment: because the id is dynamic, it is better to use class. Plus, I tried driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".Am > div")).sendKeys(mailbody); with signature, but it still sent empty body email.

Comment: @robertredrain It's not empty, it insert the content under the signature

Comment: @robertredrain Take a look at [JavaMail API](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home)